# Web Application converted to Web Site

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Will post solution I found to this problem.  I'm mostly asking for more info to prevent this from happening again.

Terminology is important here: My ASP.NET "Web Application" project got converted to a "Web Site" project, so when I open it in Visual Studio the references were all broken and when I launched it it didn't behave like an application - instead it was trying to launch static html.

Question: How do I get Visual Studio to open the project as a "Web Application" again?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the MyProjectName.csproj.webinfo files from the directory the project was in.

I have no idea when these files got created - but they were the source of the problem.